# Notification click in Android(Xamarin Forms)

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, android-notifications, xamarin.forms

I used Xamarin Form. I have an application with notifications that open a certain activity if I click them. I want that, if I click the notification and the activity is already opened, it's not started again, but just brought to front.
It is my code for notification:

```
public void Show(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
{
    var intent = CreateIntent(id);

    var localNotification = new LocalNotification();
    localNotification.Title = title;
    localNotification.Body = body;
    localNotification.Id = id;
    localNotification.NotifyTime = notifyTime;
    if (NotificationIconId != 0)
    {
        localNotification.IconId = NotificationIconId;
    }
    else
    {
        localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.Icon24;
    }

    var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
    intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    var triggerTime = NotifyTimeInMilliseconds(localNotification.NotifyTime);
    var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();

    alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

It is code in ScheduledAlarmHandler:

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
...........
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
    var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);

    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
        .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
        .SetContentText(notification.Body)
        .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
        .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))
        .SetAutoCancel(true);

    var resultIntent = LocalNotificationsService.GetLauncherActivity();
    resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
    var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
    var resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
    notificationManager.Notify(notification.Id, builder.Build());
}
....
}
```

This is atribute for my MainActivity

```
[Activity (Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,      LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
```

Comment: did you find any answer on this?

Comment: yes it is. Do you need an answer? I will write soon.

Comment: I appreciate if you share. I am looking for same problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me:

This is atribute for my MainActivity:

```
[Activity (Icon = "@drawable/icon", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,      LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "test.test.alarm" }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```

This is LocalNotificationsService

```
    public class LocalNotificationsService 
    {
     .....
    public void Show(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
    {
        var intent = CreateIntent(id);

        var localNotification = new LocalNotification();
        localNotification.Title = title;
        localNotification.Body = body;
        localNotification.Id = id;
        localNotification.NotifyTime = notifyTime;
        if (NotificationIconId != 0)
        {
            localNotification.IconId = NotificationIconId;
        }
        else
        {
            localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.Icon24;
        }

        var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
        intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        var triggerTime = NotifyTimeInMilliseconds(localNotification.NotifyTime);
        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();

        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
    }

     public static PendingIntent GetDialogPendingIntent()
     { 
        return PendingIntent.GetActivity(
            Forms.Context,
            0, 
            new Intent("test.test.alarm")
                .AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask),
            0);
     }

     private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
     {
        var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
        return alarmManager;
     }

    }
```

This is ScheduledAlarmHandler

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Local Notifications Plugin Broadcast Receiver")]
public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";


    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
        var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);
        var currPath = AppSettings.Data.NotificationSoundUri;

        var uri = string.IsNullOrEmpty(currPath) ? RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm) : Uri.Parse(currPath);
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
            .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
            .SetContentText(notification.Body)
            .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
            .SetSound(uri)
            .SetAutoCancel(true);


        var resultPendingIntent = LocalNotificationsService.GetDialogPendingIntent();
        builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
        notificationManager.Notify(notification.Id, builder.Build());
    }

    private LocalNotification DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocalNotification));
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
        {
            var notification = (LocalNotification)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            return notification;
        }
    }
}
```